# powershell find and replace all in one line

Tags: powershell, replace

I have this line of code which gives me domain\username. However, I need to replace the \ with  _. Do I have to do this multiple lines or I can do this in one line?

```
$UAN = $userProfile["AccountName"].Value
$UAN = $UAN.Replace("/","_")
```

The above does not work even if it's multiple line.

Comment: You're wainting to replace a backslash, but you have a forward slash in your replace arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-replace`

```
$UAN = ($userProfile["AccountName"].Value) -replace "\\", "_"
```